# Electron-positron pair production cannot occur in empty space

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, pair-production

I'm trying to prove that the electron-positron pair production cannot occur in empty space.
From the conservation of energy we have that
$$\hbar \omega = 2\gamma mc^2+E,$$
and from the conservation of momentum we have
$$\hbar k=2\gamma mv\cos{\theta} + p,$$
where $E$ and $p$ are the energy and momentum of some other particle being present in the process, respectively; $v$ is the velocity of electron and positron, and $theta$ is the angle at which they "fly away" (relative to the photon's path). I'm basically trying to prove that the mass of this other particle is non-zero. Since $c=\omega / k$, we have from the second eq. $\hbar \omega = 2\gamma mvc \cos{\theta} + pc$. So from both equations
$$2\gamma mc(c-v\cos{\theta})=pc-E,$$
but $c-v\cos{\theta}>0$ thus $pc-E>0$ which is unexpected, to say the least. I cannot find an error in this reasoning and yet it yields nonsense. I don't understand why this fact cannot be proven this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pair production in complete vacuum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50026/pair-production-in-complete-vacuum)

Comment: Your second equation seems wrong, it misses component of $\mathbf p$ of the third particle in direction of $\mathbf k$ before and after the event.

Comment: @JánLalinský I meant to put $+p$ in the RHS of the 2nd eq.  (I reference it later in the proof). I've edited my question.

Comment: @James I read the answer to the question you're referring to. In my question I'm asking whether this particular method of proving the existence of another particle in the reaction is valid, because I don't see why it doesn't work

Comment: Does the third particle exist before the event? If so, the first equation misses contribution due to its energy before the event. If not, your calculation shows there is no such $\theta$ that would allow for the event to obey conservation of energy and momentum.

Comment: The photon is an elementary particle with mass zero axiomatically. . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle . Vitual photons, coming from cmore complicated interactions  are mostly off mass shell.  see second paragraph of Feynman diagrams http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html